# How can i create console app that takes the values --h or --help c#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

For example, I want to create a console application, and I need to get help (list of commands, etc.). Can I create this without parsing. For example, I want to open a list of commands on page 2. The command will look like так:.../programm.ехе -- help 2. Indiscriminately. Is that impossible? Maybe c# can do it.

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing built into .NET that will automatically handle this. You can of course have a `string[] args` parameter to your Main method, but then you will need to look at the contents of this array and write logic to process it. There are probably nuget packages you can use that automates what you need.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This is the one most people use https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline

Comment: @DavidG yeah i know. I just saw something like this without parsing, but it looks like it was somehow sewn in by libraries.

Comment: Parser from [microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api), though it is still in preview)

Answer (score 3):

approach without any third party library

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)        
    {
        if (args.Any(x => x == "--help" || x == "--h"))
        {
            //get help
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this package

```
Install-Package CommandLineParser -Version 2.8.0
```

with source on github

https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline

Comment: It would probably be beneficial if you added a small example instead of just the link.